# Parameter index out of range MySQL PreparedStatement?

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I try to do a select:

[image]

but I receive an Exception:
[image]

Comment: I think parameter is not passing anything meaning in your sql '?' was not replace any value. Because of that you got that error. simple replace '?' with value and then check that run or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like that:

```
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlCompetition);
preparedStatement.setInt(...);
```

I think you have still the old statement in the variable

Answer (score 1):

You are creating `PrepareStatement` object at `line number 212` but you are not assigning to the `prepareStatement` variable, which means `prepareStatement` variable still holds old object.

At `line number 213` you are using `setInt()` method, it'll calls the old object. It seems your old object contains any place holders, because of the this reason you got `Parameter index out of range exception`.

Assign the newly created `PreparedStatement` object to `prepareStatement` variable at `line number 212` to resolve your problem.